# shell script monitor mutiple connections with same IP

Tags: linux, shell, netstat

I'm trying to monitor connections coming into a Linux server which have the same IP's connected to the same port. Is it possible to monitor a specific ip address to alert only if it doesn't exist 2 times?

Example:

netstat -an |grep 000

```
101.101.101.101:2000        ESTABLISHED
101.101.101.101:2000        ESTABLISHED
101.101.101.102:3000        ESTABLISHED
101.101.101.102:3000        ESTABLISHED
```

I'd like to alert if 101.101.101.101 or 101.101.102 doesn't exit 2 times each regardless of the port.

My script:

```
connections=('101.101.101.101' '101.101.101.102')
running=( $(netstat -an |grep 000 |awk '{print $1}') )
non_running=()
for process_name in ${connections[@]}; do
    if [[ "${running[*]}" == *$process_name* ]]; then
        echo "$process_name is running"
    else
        echo "$process_name is not running"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Following script could help you in same.

```
netstat -an | awk -v s1="\"" '
function check(ip,count,email_id){
  if(count<2){
    system("echo " s1 "IP " ip " 2 count not found." s1 " |  mailx -s " s1 " Alert email IP " ip " 2 times occurence not found." s1 FS email_id)
}
  else{
    print ip " is running fine."}
}
/101.101.101.101/{
  count1++
}
/101.101.101.102/{
  count2++
}
END{
  check(101.101.101.101,count1,"test@chumma.com");
  check(101.101.101.102,count2,"test@chumma.com")
}
'
```

***Explanation:*** So it will run the command `netstat -an` and put it's standard output as standard input for `awk` command. In `awk` command if you see I created a `function` named `check`, so you could call it for any IP(which we have to do check it's count while standard input is getting read), in END block of `awk` you could call this function with attributes passed to it `eg--> check(IP,count_variable,your_email_where_you_want_to_alert)`. It should print if All is Well(means count of that variable is greater or equal to 2, if you only want count 2 then change my code's condition to `count==2` above function) else it will send email to id which you will provide to function.

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13 I used your suggestion and it works except that if both IP address' are down, it only alerts on one of them in the email alert. I couldn't figure out how to alert on both if both are down. Also, I should of added, the first ip should exist 2 times and the second IP should exist 4 times. is there a simple solution to alert if 10.101.101.101 alerts if less than two exist and 10.101.101.102 alerts if less than 4 exists? Thanks!!

Comment: @connollyc4, condition where I have mentioned count<2, you could change to count<4. Also it worked for me I got 2 emails when I tested for my IPs, please make sure your IPs are having less count than 2 then it should send email for both to your id, let me know how it goes then.